# Mule: Memory Leak on use a custom-transformer at the end of flow

Tags: mule

We process XML-Files from the Filesystem and once they've been process, they will be moved to another directory. Another system monitors this output folder and takes all newly created files for further process.

If we define the moveToPattern and moveToDirecory properties, the input file will be first copied to destinations and then deleted from input folder. This works properly on small files but takes longer on huge files which causes to incomplete file on output folder for some seconds.

Our solution is to let the file be copied with .tmp extension and then rename it to the final name and delete the input file.

So the Flow looks like below:

Input-File --> Processing --> Output-File with .tmp --> Rename --> Delete Input-File

The Problem is through using this custom-transformer for renaming the file after the file:endpoint the flow remains active and all Messages won't be garbage collected and causes a OutOfMemory Exception.
A Memory Dump shows a huge number of DefaultMuleMessage object which proofs my assumption.

has anybody an Idea to resolve this Problem?

```
<file:connector name="inputFileConnector" autoDelete="false" doc:name="File" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" />

<file:connector name="temporaryFileOutputConnectorConfig" outputPattern="#[message.outboundProperties['transportFileName']].tmp" autoDelete="false" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" />
<file:endpoint path="${outputDir}/${queuePrefix}#[message.outboundProperties.'queue_number' ]/#[message.outboundProperties.'approvalSubDir']" name="OutputConnectorEndpoint" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>


<flow name="Queue_Flow" processingStrategy="synchronous" initialState="stopped" >
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="${inputDir}" responseTimeout="10000" pollingFrequency="5000" connector-ref="inputFileConnector" doc:name="File">
    .
    .
    .
    <flow-ref name="OutStrategyFile" doc:name="Out Strategy File"/>
</flow>

<sub-flow name="OutStrategyFile">
    <file:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="temporaryFileOutputConnectorConfig" responseTimeout="10000" ref="OutputConnectorEndpoint" doc:name="Write temporary file"/>
    <custom-transformer class="com.fileutil.FileRenamer" doc:name="Rename file to final location">
        <spring:property name="fileUtils" ref="fileUtils"/>
    </custom-transformer>
    <custom-transformer class="com.fileutil.DeleteOriginalInputMessage" doc:name="Delete Original input message"/>
</sub-flow>
```

Comment: Why using two different file connectors? Especially one in streaming and the other one not... I'm wondering if this is messing with Mule's inbound/outbound file streaming bridge that usually works great.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I am with memory problem too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616462/mule-memory-leak-poll-database-processing-in-for-each

Comment: I have answered directly in your issue